# Branch and Release flow for distributed teams in a Monorepo

Tags: github, continuous-integration, devops, monorepo, nrwl-nx

We are trying to move 3 angular apps(using NX workspace) from their own repo to a single repository/monorepo because they can share lot of code and assets from common libs, currently all these apps are being handled by their independent teams and they have their own release cycle and sprints.

But moving them to same repo we are not able to decide how we can setup a branching & release strategy so that each app can be deployed independently can have their own release cycles?

And teams can manage what feature can be move to staging and production?